# Can't launch from an object

Tags: scala

I'm using the current version of the TypeSafe Scala/eclipse IDE. I have an object (which I called `PositionObj` to give it a unique name). `PositionObj` contains a `main` method. Yet when I try `Run as > Scala application` I get a pop-up message saying:

`PositionObj needs to be an 'object' (it is currently a 'class').`

In fact it's not a class, and there is no class with that name. Any thoughts about why this is happening and how I can get around it?

Here is the relevant code.

```
object PositionObj { ...

    def main(args: Array[String] = Array[String]()): Unit = {
       // This is just to see if anything happens.
       println(position(3).p1Rqmts.keys.head)
    }
    ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post relevant parts of your `PositionObj`? (object declaration plus main at least)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answered-to code, try removing the default argument, since this might be creating a different code signature

Answer (score 0):

I should have done this before, but now I notice that there is a compiler error message that says that the compiler couldn't handle the code because it was too big for a method.  That's consistent with my experience with the problem. When I comment out a large table of data, everything works fine.  So I'm now convinced that the problem was simply that the program was organized in a way that pieces of it were too large to be handled by the compiler.

I got around the problem by chopping my data table into multiple parts and including each one in a separate object. That worked even though all the objects were then included in the overall program. It was not the size of the program overall; it was the size of large chunks.

The compiler error message was somewhat misleading in that it said the problem was that a method was too large. In fact, my data table was a `val` in an `object` and not within a method. But as I said, chopping it up into separate objects and combing them with software solved the problem.